# how to pass fieldname dynamically in mogodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to pass field name dynamically in Mondgodb while query the collection. e.g.

```
emp.ply = function(res,res) {
  Employee.find({area: 'Plymouth'}).exec(function(err,PLY) {
    res.render("../index", {resultset: PLY})
```

here I'm doing query on field name area which is hard code. Instead of i want to pass fieldname dynamically. How we can achieve it in nodeJS

Comment: store your fieldname in a variable and use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

So, conceptually you just need to build the query object before sending it to the `.find()` function.  Perhaps something like this:

```
const query = {}
const fieldname = 'area'
const fieldvalue = 'Plymouth'
query[fieldname] = fieldvalue
Employee.find(query).exec((err, ply) => {
  // do whatever
});
```

You could conceptually extract both fieldname and fielvalue from req.body or req.query depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for your response. I tried it but i did not get any result. Could you please double check for query constant

Comment: I don’t understand your question. What I wrote will work, if it’s not working for you please post what you did.

Answer (score 1):

If your code supports ES6 or (any latest browser except IE), we can do this:

```
emp.ply = function(res,res) {
  let searchField = 'area'; // this can be anything dynamically
  Employee.find({[searchField]: 'Plymouth'}).exec(function(err,PLY) {
    res.render("../index", {resultset: PLY})
    })
}
```

You can refer to MDN docs about [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Thank you Dabishan. It is helpful.